# asp.net Core MVC 2 - configure CORS to accept NULL origin

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to configure a web api implemented using asp.net core 2.2 to accept a "null" origin ('Origin' header missing or empty).

Before you jump down my throat: I know that having a null origin is bad. But there's unfortunately nothing I can do about it, because the call is made by a third party server that passes a null origin and I have no control over it, so I need to make my api accept a null origin.

I tried doing this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
}

...

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    //Configuring CORS
    services.AddCors();
}
```

but it doesn't make any difference. When I make a POST request (using jQuery's ajax method), I get the following error:

[image]

I have the suspicion that a null/missing origin is just discarded before even checking it... am I right? Is there any way to accept a null origin?

Comment: What is actually happening that makes you think there's a problem? You haven't mentioned any actual exceptions or failures.

Comment: @UncleDave: you're right, I've edited the question with the error

Comment: Your question refers to the call being made by a third party "server", whereas the screenshot is clearly chrome dev tools, meaning you're sending the request from the browser. This is a very important distinction as the browser is the thing that blocks responses due to CORS, not the server. Therefore if you WERE to make a request from another server and not a browser, then CORS wouldn't enter into the equation. However if you intend to send requests from the browser trying moving `app.UseCors` above `app.UseMvc`.

Comment: @UncleDave: I solved the problem (see my answer). But to answer your question: yes, I'm using my browser, but the page I am on is on a server that I have no control over. The page in question contains several pieces "plug-in style" and uses some sandboxing tricks to isolate each of these pieces (I think it uses iframes to do it). The result is that if you make a call from one of those "isolated" pieces the origin that goes out is null, even if I am on a "real" page with a proper domain name and everything.

Comment: What a coincidence, I also solved the problem! (see the end of my comment above).

Comment: @UncleDave: lol, sorry, I only read the first lines of your comment and I thought you were just pointing out the browser thing ;) Reformulate your comment as an actual answer and I'll be happy to accept it (and there's no need to spam the question with -1 -_-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CORS middleware must be placed before the MVC middleware, or the MVC middleware (and your controller) will send the response without allowing the CORS middleware a chance to run.

Change your configure method to this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
    app.UseMvc(); // Add this middleware last.
}
```

The order of `AddMvc` and `AddCors` in the `ConfigureServices` method does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. The problem was very simple: the `UseCors()` and `AddCors()` methods in the Startup class must be called BEFORE the `UseMvc()` and `AddMvc()` methods.